Stripe URL different between the desktop link and the link from the logs
I got a problem in stripe implementation.
#[Route('/buy/{subjectId}', name: 'buy_subject', methods: ['POST'])]
public function buySubject(Request $request, $subjectId, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry, $stripeSK): Response
{
$entityManager = $managerRegistry->getManager();
$subject = $entityManager->getRepository(Subject::class)->find($subjectId);
    error_log('Subject ID: ' . $subjectId);

    if (!$subject) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Subject not found');
    }

    dump($subject);

    Stripe::setApiKey($stripeSK);

    error_log('Stripe API Key: ' . $stripeSK);

    $totalAmount = $subject->getSubjectPrice() * 100;

    error_log('Total Amount: ' . $totalAmount);

    // Debugging URLs
    error_log('Success URL: ' . $this->generateUrl('subject_success'));
    error_log('Cancel URL: ' . $this->generateUrl('subject_cancel'));

    $checkoutSession = Session::create([
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => [[
            'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => $subject->getSubjectName(),
                ],
                'unit_amount' => $totalAmount,
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'success_url' => $this->generateUrl('subject_success', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
        'cancel_url' => $this->generateUrl('subject_cancel', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
    ]);

    return $this->redirect($checkoutSession->url);
}

The link when I click the buy button is not the same as when I access the logs.
The link I access after clicking the button is "Something went wrong
The page you were looking for could not be found. Please check the URL or contact the merchant."
But when I access the URL link from the logs I can access the stripe checkout form normally.
Why are the two links different and how can I fix it?-
